# C#: naming rules for protected members fields

Tags: c#, .net, naming-conventions

In our .NET software component we use the following naming convention. When a customer use our DLL from VB.NET, the compiler cannot distinguish `distance` member field from the `Distance` property. What workaround do you recommend?

Thanks.

```
public class Dimension : Text
{
    private string _textPrefix;

    protected double distance;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the real measured distance.
    /// </summary>
    public double Distance
    {
        get { return Math.Abs(distance); }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd personally make the field private to start with. Why do you really need the field to be protected?

Comment: Name the field `_distance` instead?

Comment: @Jon: We need the actual value in derived classes

Comment: @Visual: We don't want to confuse private with protected member fields

Comment: `p_distance` then? Or `m_distance`? If you are using an IDE with IntelliSense you should be able to see the difference between the type of access to the fields via the icon that IntelliSense gives it.

Comment: I'd still make the field `private` and add `protected setter` to the property instead

Comment: @Alberto `_` or `m` prefix is used to remove ambiguity and intellisense mistakes.

Comment: IntelliSense will tell you when a member is protected or private. So will the compiler. You do not need a naming convention to distinguish between these things. If you did, you'd name them `privTextPrefix` and `protDistance`, and nobody wants that. Just use a leading underscore, or reconsider having protected fields in the first place.

Comment: I'd probably have two properties, personally. `AbsoluteDistance` and (protected) `RawDistance` or something like that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should not use fields that are protected, for the reason that versioning and access cannot be guarded. See the [Field Design](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229057.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) guidelines. Change your field to a property, which will also force you to change to name (as you cannot have two properties with the same name). Or, if possible, make the protected field private.

To make setting your property accessible only to the inheriting classes, use a protected setter:

```
public class Dimension : Text
{
    private string _textPrefix;

    private double _absoluteDistance;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the real measured distance.
    /// </summary>
    public double Distance
    {
        get { return _absoluteDistance  }
        protected set { _absoluteDistance = Math.Abs(distance); }
    }
}
```

Although that does cause divergence between get and set, as functionality is not the same. Perhaps a separate protected method would be better in this case:

```
public class Dimension : Text
{
    private string _textPrefix;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the real measured distance.
    /// </summary>
    public double Distance { get; private set; }

    protected void SetAbsoluteDistance(double distance)
    {
        Distance = Math.Abs(distance);
    }
}
```

Comment: What were protected member fields designed for then?

Comment: The fact that something is possible does not mean it should be used.

Comment: @WicherVisser What does _versioning_ mean in this context?

Comment: Bad choice of words. I meant "change": change internal to the class.

Answer (score 3):

Well, summarizing of what already being said you can do something like this :

```
public class Dimension : Text
{
    private string _textPrefix;

    private double _rawDistance;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the real measured distance.
    /// </summary>
    public double AbsoluteDistance
    {
        get; private set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the raw distance
    /// </summary>
    public double RawDistance
    {
        get { return _rawDistance; }
        protected set { _rawDistance = value; AbsoluteDistance = Math.Abs(value); }
    }
}
```

When `RawDistance`'s value is set it also sets value for `AbsoluteDistance` and because of that there is no need to invoke `Math.Abs()` in `getter` of "AbsoluteDistance".

Comment: I would work but it's too complicated and difficult to maintain. Thanks for your effort...